# how to design right to left linear layout

Tags: android, android-layout

First sorry about my weak English language!

I designed a layout. This is part of the layout:

```
 <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_details"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dip" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_details_ostan"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="Medium Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#0000FF" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="استان"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#AA0000" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Preferred language direction is right to left. The red colors are topic, and the blue ones are text that will read from database.

The problem is that the text has many characters and when shown in this layout, the topic will be disappeared  because of my layout is "left to right" and the text fill all layout.

I searched a lot but I can't find any way to change the layout "right to left".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try doing this:

1. Change your LinearLayout to a RelativeLayout
2. Align the topic to parent right
3. Put subject text to left of the topic

Here's an example:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dip" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:text="استان"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#AA0000" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_details_ostan"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView3"
                android:text="This is a sample of a long message. It will not push the topic off screen."
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#0000FF" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: android:layoutDirection="rtl" this is a better solution, as shown in: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:layoutDirection

Comment: کلک مرغابی زدی:) ولی راست به چپ نیست

Answer (score 25):

Add the following line to your layout:

```
android:layoutDirection="rtl"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

Comment: if in manifest support rtl is false then layoutDirection not working

Answer (score 0):

if you come here, then you should not miss [this](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout) magic solution called flexbox.

you can arrange items from left to right or vise versa for top to down just with changing one parameter.

example:

```
                    <com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout
                    android:paddingLeft="12dp"
                    android:paddingRight="12dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    app:alignContent="flex_start"
                    app:alignItems="flex_start"

                    app:flexWrap="wrap">
<Item1/>
<Item2/>
<Item3/>
<Item4/>
<Item5/>
    </com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout>
```

above five items are arranged from left to right.
you just need to add one line so you can arrange it from right to left.
this line is:

```
                        app:flexDirection="row_reverse"
```

it will be like this:

```
                    <com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout
                    android:paddingLeft="12dp"
                    android:paddingRight="12dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    app:alignContent="flex_start"
                    app:alignItems="flex_start"
                    app:flexDirection="row_reverse"
                    app:flexWrap="wrap">
```

Answer (score 0):

One mistake I can see here if you putting left and right fixed margin.
Eg - 10 and 10 from left and right, then you should set the **>=** from right margin. it help to get right to left content.